# How to add tags for every batch data in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

if I set a batch interval of 5 seconds(`Seconds(5)`), every 5 seconds, I add a tag for current batch data. if I can add tags for every batch data, when I use `window()` function, I can filter data by tags.

**1st 5 seconds** input some data:

```
hello
word
hello
```

after add tags for data like this:

```
(1st, hello)     // "1st" is the custom tag that can identify this batch data
(1st, word)
(1st, hello)
```

**2nd 5 seconds** input some data:

```
spark
streaming
interval
time
```

after add tags for data:

```
(2nd, spark)
(2nd, streaming)
(2nd, interval)
(2nd, time)
```

Comment: Bit confusing and difficult to understand. Please provide some examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry, my english is very poor. I update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 Options: -

1. The best way would be to add some identifications within the messages itself, so that while you receive you already have something which can identify each message.
2. Second Option would be to create [Custom receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/streaming-custom-receivers.html) which can identify the message Batch and add some tags and then further send it to Spark Job.
3. The final option would be to leverage [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/programming-guide.html#accumulators). Something like this: -

   ```
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   var accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
   val recDStream = //Write Code to get the Stream
   recDStream.foreachRDD(x => "Data for Batch-"+(accum+=1)+"-"+x)
   //Or may be you can add Accumulator after the forEach, 
   //so that it becomes for a whole Batch something like accum.add(1)
   ```